# CoreData crashes when saving Main Object Context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nscoding

When I move my application to the background, CoreData seems to crash as soon as I save the mainObjectContext. In the console I am seeing the following error:

```
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000064c7ac0> , -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000319de00 with userInfo of (null)
```

The method to save the main object context is implemented like this:

```
func save() {
    if mainManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        mainManagedObjectContext.performAndWait {
            do {
                try mainManagedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ManagedObjectContextSaveError, object: nil)
            }
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .MainManagedObjectContextSaved, object: nil)
    }
}
```

This method is called from `AppDelegate.applicationWillResignActive(_:)`
I am not sure why encodeWithCoder is being called here and why it would crash.

In fact, I am not even sure how to further troubleshoot it from here.

Comment: If you have a property on one of your managed object subclasses, that is a type that CoreData will have to encode to store properly, it's use an encoder.

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw There is a property of type "Transferable", would this be stored using an encoder?

Comment: I removed the transferables and store these objects differently in CoreData now. This seems to have resolved the crash, the CoreData saves correctly. Still I don't know how I should have debugged this or how I could find out which of my Entities it was crashing on. Thanks for leading me to into the right direction @AndrewTetlaw

Comment: Hey no problem. CoreData can be a black box full of magic sometimes...